# Reducing "How do I ask an academic a question?" questions

Tags: discussion

Academia gets a lot of questions in this genre.

https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=how+to+ask

Many of the asker's problems could be solved if they reworded their post to be addressed to the academic in question, and then asked the question.  I feel like these posts are just looking for affirmation.  They contribute to the noise rather than the signal.  Can we make a catch-all question or otherwise reduce these?

Comment: Questions about academics asking students questions seem more interesting to me.

Comment: Looking at the top ~ten questions on that list, it doesn't seem like there could be a (useful) common answer for all (or even many) of them.

Comment: Not all the questions linked are in the genre.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a list of questions that you think this proposal would apply to, then.

Answer (score 8):

If I understand your concern, I think that there are two genres of questions embedded within the "how to ask" that might be good for setting up community wiki answers for:

- "How do I effectively ask a busy stranger for help with admission/funding/hiring/research?"
- "When should I treat professors as authority figures and when like ordinary human beings?"

The rest I think are highly heterogeneous, but we get a lot that are basically students or junior researchers who are struggling with these two general issues, and a CW might be able to help consolidate them.

Comment: Right.  These questions are not really about the stated situation.  They are about the asker's self confidence.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist It's not just self-confidence, it's also about complying with social norms.  If you ask a busy stranger for help in a problematic manner, you are guaranteed to not get help.  Likewise, there are some times when you *should* treat a professor as an authority figure and not an ordinary fellow human being.